# How to hold the state of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have two such arrays :

```
var array1 = ["apple", "pear", "cherry", "orange", "mango"];
var array2 = [false, false, false, false, false];
```

When I'm going through `array1` , I modify some of its elements. And I turn respective element in `array2` to true. For example, if `array1` becomes

```
["apple", "pearX", "cherry", "orange", "mango"]
```

`array2` becomes :

```
[false, true, false, false, false]
```

I will not modify `"pearX"` anymore since it is true in `array2`. And I should stop modifying `array1` when `array2` becomes all `true`. Moreover I can't modify all of `array1` at once because `"apple"`'s value might depend on `"pear"`'s

For solving this problem, first I made a for loop and put it inside a while loop  like this :

```
var isComplete = false

while(isComplete == false)
{
for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
  {
     // do some stuff
     if(/*all elements in array2 is true*/)
        {
          isComplete = true;
          break;
        }
  }
}
```

This didn't work because for loop is trying to modify all elements at once, it is not waiting for other elements' value to change. It was modifying all of the `array1` elements asynchronously.

Then I replaced for loop with array.forEach. But it didn't work because I couldn't find a proper way to stop forEeach loop.

As you can see this problem is not rocket science but I couldn't solve it myself since I'm new to Javascript programming. Can you help me to find a working solution to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: you need to store the old `array1`, then compare for getting `array2`.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ "This didn't work because for loop is async." - it is not. "I couldn't find a proper way to stop forEeach loop" - you can't stop it unless throwing an error.

Comment: @NickA Yes. When I work on nth element in `array1`, I will change nth element in `array2` to `true`

Comment: @jason a concrete example may be helpful, how are you deciding which elements are ready to be updated, what do you mean by *"It was modifying all of the array1 elements asynchronously."*

Comment: Are you perhaps asking how to skip elements you've already modified? I'm unsure about what your code isn't doing right because I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MechaLynx Yes, that would work as well. But I also need to be sure that all elements are modified finally.

Comment: @jason I think I understand now - you can perform this check to see if all the elements in `array2` are `true`: `! array2.includes(false)`. This will return `false` if they're all `true`, so you negate it to allow the `if` to succeed. `if ( ! array2.includes(false) )` should work. Here's an [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). By the way, please be clear on how the code _isn't_ doing what you expect it to next time. Add a few examples like NickA said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this kind of issues I think it better to use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you want to synchronize multiple asynchronous changes, using promises is easy to find out when all the changes are done.

See the below snippet

```js
var array1 = ["apple", "pear", "cherry", "orange", "mango"];
var array2 = [false, false, false, false, false];
var promises = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        array1[i] += "X";
        array2[i] = true;
        resolve(array1[i]);
      }, randomRange(100,500));
    });
    promises.push(p);
  }

  Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
    console.log(values); 
  });

function randomRange(min, max) {
  return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what `~~` does in your `randomRange` function?

Comment: It is used as a faster replacement for Math.floor().

Comment: i will make the changes for a better understanding

Comment: Thanks for the explaination :)